# How to create curve triangle in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Hi all I am new to react native and try to develop below UI.Is they any ways to create a curve triangle.I tried but unable curve edge of triangle.
[image]

Here is my code.

```
 notch: {
    width: 32,
    height: 5,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    borderStyle: 'solid',
    borderLeftWidth: 30 / 2,
    borderRightWidth: 30 / 2,
    borderBottomWidth: 20,
    borderLeftColor: 'transparent',
    borderRightColor: 'transparent',
    borderBottomColor: '#7B1B67',
    position: 'absolute',
    right: 15,
    top: -15,
    borderTopLeftRadius: 15,
    borderTopRightRadius: 15,
    borderBottomLeftRadius: 95,
    borderBottomRightRadius: 95,
    overflow:'visible'


},
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple square element, round the border then rotate it. Here's an example where`::after` is just for preview

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  background: purple;
  border-radius: .5rem;
  padding: .75rem;
  color:white;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

.wrapper::before, .wrapper::after {
  content: "";
  display:block;
  width: 30px;
  aspect-ratio:1/1;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: -10px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, purple 50%, transparent 50%);
  border-radius: 30%;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.wrapper::after {
  left: 20px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, orange 50%, transparent 50%);
}
```

```html
<br>
<div class="wrapper">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus dolor veritatis, cum accusantium fugit modi, exercitationem, accusamus unde assumenda illum aperiam laborum dignissimos voluptatem explicabo optio praesentium quae veniam tempora.</div>
```

##### Note

`linear-gradient` is just to fill half so it doesn't hide the text, you may use z-index and simply push it below text

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, purple 50%, transparent 50%);
```